# Jquery inline Datepicker with form field and restricted date range

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, range, inline

I've taken the code posted on this site in order to get the inline datepicker display the selected date in a form field.
http://elementdesignllc.com/demos/datepicker_inline.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
    $("#datepicker_value").val(dateText);
}
    });

    });
```

When trying to implement the restricted date range the code keeps failing.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
});
</script>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions even though some did not assist. This morning I managed to get it solved
Here is the code for others that might be stuck in the same situation

```
<input id="Range" type="hidden" value="2012/11/10"/ name="newdate">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fromCalendar").datepicker({ altField: "#Range", altFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', minDate: +65, maxDate: "+94D", defaultDate: +64  });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4kpWp/3/

In your code you've set up 2 "datepickers" referring to the same ID, I would just use 1 datepicker with the ID #datepicker.

Comment: That code works fine when displaying the calendar object as a popup, the issue I am having is when displaying it inline, with a form, and with restricted dates.

Thanks for your response.